# Menu type program

Tags: c, function, menu, linked-list, structure

I have an assignment to write a program for supporting an art gallery in C. It has to be menu based program using lists. I wrote the first function of the menu and I need some help writing the other three. So I have a structure of an unique code of the painting, author's name, painting's name, price, year of the painting. I have to create a function deleting a painting using the unique code, print out all the info about every painting and modifying a painting again using said code. The data has to be in a dynamic type structure using a linked list. This is the program so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void addPainting(void);
void erasePainting(void);
void printData(void);
void modifyData(void);

int main()
{

    struct paintings
    {
        char code[20];
        char name[50];
        char paintingName[50];
        double price;
        int year;

    }painting[100];
    int choice;
    do
    {
        printf("Menu\n");
        printf("To add a painting press 1.\n");
        printf("To erase a painting press 2.\n");
        printf("To print data for all paintings by authors alphabetically press 3.\n");
        printf ("To modify data for a painting press 4.\n");
        printf("To exit the program press 5.\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
           case 1:
            {
                addPainting();
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                erasePainting();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                printData();
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                modifyData();
                break;
            }

            default: printf ("Wrong choice. Try again\n");
                break;
        }
    }while (choice !=5);



void addPainting()
{
    FILE *fp;


    struct paintings painting;
    printf("Enter code:");
    scanf("%s", &painting.code);
    printf("Enter the name of the author:");
    scanf("%s", &painting.name);
    printf("Enter the name of the painting:");
    scanf("%s", &painting.paintingName);
    printf("Enter price:");
    scanf("%lf", &painting.price);
    printf("Enter the year of creation:");
    scanf("%d", &painting.year);
      if ((fp=fopen("paintings","wb"))==NULL)
        exit(1);
    if ((fwrite (&painting,sizeof(painting),1,fp)!=1))
        exit(2);
    fclose(fp);

}



}
```

Comment: The function `addPainting()` seems to be nested in `main()`

Comment: Please don't define functions/structs inside other functions...

Comment: Welcome! It would be nice if you told us what exactly is your issue so we can help you. Just "it does not work" is not enough for us.

Comment: I have to write the three functions I mentioned and I have no idea how and where to start. This is the issue.

Comment: `addPainting()` will create a file with only one record, overwriting previous records, unless you change the open mode to `"ab"` to append.

Comment: Your code as is will not compile.  You have to get that first before going forward to the other questions, but, there are many tutorials on how to create and use linked lists in C.  ***[Here is one](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists)***.  Google _Linked Lists in C_ for more.

Comment: How do I fix the error: storage size of 'painting' isn't known?

Comment: Storage size problem is due to local scope of struct.  It is not known in the function because you created it with local scope in main().  (see below)

Answer (score 0):

First problem:   You are missing the closing brace ( `}` ) for the main() function. (but I am sure you knew that)

***The reason for the struct size error is that*** you are attempting to create an instance of `struct painting` in the  `void addPainting()` function, when it was created with local scope in the main function, and therefore ***it is not visible to the function***.   Create `struct painting` with global scope if you want to use it this way:

***This will build (and run)*** but only for the functions defined, the others are commented out.  There are other problems you will have to work out, or ask about.

***EDITED*** to fix scanf() statements, show use of fopen()/fclose(), create and write strings using sprintf()/fputs()...

```
void addPainting(void);
//void erasePainting(void);
//void printData(void);
//void modifyData(void);

typedef    struct //created with global scope, visible to all functions
{
    char code[20];
    char name[50];
    char paintingName[50];
    double price;
    int year;

}PAINTING;

PAINTING painting[100];//array of instance of PAINTING

#define PATH "C:\\play\\painting.txt"  //edit to your need


int main()
{

    int choice;
    do
    {
        printf("Menu\n");
        printf("To add a painting press 1.\n");
        printf("To erase a painting press 2.\n");
        printf("To print data for all paintings by authors alphabetically press 3.\n");
        printf ("To modify data for a painting press 4.\n");
        printf("To exit the program press 5.\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
           case 1:
            {
                addPainting();
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                //erasePainting();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                //printData();
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                //modifyData();
                break;
            }

            default: printf ("Wrong choice. Try again\n");
                break;
        }
    }while (choice !=5);
}

void addPainting(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char stringToWrite[80];
    //Note: this function could be prototyped with an int argument
    //        to be used as an index for the array arguments of your
    //        structure.  Currently, the indexes are hard-coded to 0, 


    printf("Enter code:");
    //scanf("%s", &painting[0].code); 
    scanf("%s", painting[0].code); //& not needed for char array (char *) et. al.
    printf("Enter the name of the author:");
    scanf("%s", painting[0].name);
    printf("Enter the name of the painting:");
    scanf("%s", painting[0].paintingName);
    printf("Enter price:");
    scanf("%lf", &painting[0].price);
    printf("Enter the year of creation:");
    scanf("%d", &painting[0].year);
    fp = fopen (PATH, "a");//open for create/append text file (not write binary, "wb")

    if(fp)
    {
        sprintf(stringToWrite, "Painting Code is: %s\n", painting[0].code);
        fputs(stringToWrite, fp);
        // do others same way...
        //...
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Most importantly, the painting database will be wiped out each time `addPainting` is called.

Comment: @szczurcio - There are many other things wrong.  But OP has to ask.  The question I answered is the only one asked so far (struct size error)

Comment: So how do I make it that when addPainting is called it adds a painting to the exsiting ones, not deleting the database?

Comment: @TsvetomirPavlov The problem is your `fopen` call. Read the manual: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: @TsvetomirPavlov - I have made an edit to the struct definition (used typedef ) and edited function as well.  Once you use fopen() to create a file, you can write strings using several methods.  I will edit once again to illustrate creating a string and writing it to file using fputs().  (give me a minute)